# photodiode, ldr and light source

Tags: photodiode, ldr, light-sensor

I need to measure the red or green or blue component of a light source. Are there any resistor or diode with this specific capability? I found some diode with rgb filter, but i'd want to know if there are something more specific.

thanks

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11195

Answer (score 1):

There are chips that already do what you want. There is really no need to build your own thing out of color filters and diodes.

Take a look at the TCS3103 or TCS3104 from AMS for example. They output three voltages which are proportional to the incoming red, green and blue light components.